# set weight units in grams

Tags: magento, fedex

i am using magento to sell jewelry products , i want my weight to be set in grams , not in kg or grams , i tried searching and found only two kg and pounds.

weights are important is used by fedex for calculation .

please guide me where can i find setting to edit it .

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't allow you to change the unit for Fedex Shipping in the backend. You will need to overwrite this file in you app/code/local and change unit:

/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/FedEx.php

```
 RequestedPackageLineItems' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'Weight' => array(
                    'Value' => (float)$r->getWeight(),
                    'Units' => 'LBS'
                ),
                'GroupPackageCount' => 1,
            )
```